# How to change CameraSceneNodeFPS keybindings at run time?

Tags: c++, irrlicht

Fairly self explanatory. I would like to be able to change the keybindings for an FPS camera in [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/). I know how to change the keybindings when the camera is created, but after that I cannot find a way to do it. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to start out with a normal camera node and then attach a SceneNodeAnimatorCameraFPS

```
irr::scene::ICameraSceneNode* camera;
irr::scene::ISceneNodeAnimatorCameraFPS* ca;


camera = _smngr->addCameraSceneNode();

irr::core::array<irr::SKeyMap> keyMap;

keyMap[0].Action = EKA_MOVE_FORWARD;
keyMap[0].KeyCode = KEY_UP;
keyMap[1].Action = EKA_MOVE_FORWARD;
keyMap[1].KeyCode = KEY_KEY_W;

keyMap[2].Action = EKA_MOVE_BACKWARD;
keyMap[2].KeyCode = KEY_DOWN;
keyMap[3].Action = EKA_MOVE_BACKWARD;
keyMap[3].KeyCode = KEY_KEY_S;

keyMap[4].Action = EKA_STRAFE_LEFT;
keyMap[4].KeyCode = KEY_LEFT;
keyMap[5].Action = EKA_STRAFE_LEFT;
keyMap[5].KeyCode = KEY_KEY_A;

keyMap[6].Action = EKA_STRAFE_RIGHT;
keyMap[6].KeyCode = KEY_RIGHT;
keyMap[7].Action = EKA_STRAFE_RIGHT;
keyMap[7].KeyCode = KEY_KEY_D;


ca->setKeyMap(keyMap);
camera->addAnimator(ca);
```

You if you want to change the keybindings later on, then just change the right Keycode and use

```
ca->setKeyMap(keyMap);
```

again.

:)

EDIT:
You can also access the Animator that is attached by the scene manager

```
camera = _smngr->addCameraSceneNodeFPS();

irr::core::list<irr::scene::ISceneNodeAnimator*>::ConstIterator al = camera->getAnimators().begin();
irr::scene::ISceneNodeAnimatorCameraFPS *a = (irr::scene::ISceneNodeAnimatorCameraFPS*)*al;


irr::core::array<irr::SKeyMap> keyMap;

keyMap[0].Action = EKA_MOVE_FORWARD;
keyMap[0].KeyCode = KEY_UP;
keyMap[1].Action = EKA_MOVE_FORWARD;
keyMap[1].KeyCode = KEY_KEY_W;

keyMap[2].Action = EKA_MOVE_BACKWARD;
keyMap[2].KeyCode = KEY_DOWN;
keyMap[3].Action = EKA_MOVE_BACKWARD;
keyMap[3].KeyCode = KEY_KEY_S;

keyMap[4].Action = EKA_STRAFE_LEFT;
keyMap[4].KeyCode = KEY_LEFT;
keyMap[5].Action = EKA_STRAFE_LEFT;
keyMap[5].KeyCode = KEY_KEY_A;

keyMap[6].Action = EKA_STRAFE_RIGHT;
keyMap[6].KeyCode = KEY_RIGHT;
keyMap[7].Action = EKA_STRAFE_RIGHT;
keyMap[7].KeyCode = KEY_KEY_D;


a->setKeyMap(keyMap);
```